# Why is $\Re \zeta$ non-zero on the line $\Re(s)=\frac32$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

I am trying to understand why $\Re \zeta (s)$ is non-zero on the line $\Re (s)=\frac32$. This in stated without explanation in section 6.6 of the book ‘Riemann’s Zeta Function’ by H.M. Edwards, and it is a key part in Backlund’s proof for the evaluation of $N(T)$ (number of complex zeta roots below $t=T$).

Using the zeta formula, I have deduced for $s=3/2 +iT$, we have

$$ \Re \zeta (s)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(T \log n)}{n^{3/2}}.$$

How can one show this summation must be non-zero?

Comment: I don't have a concrete answer to this yet, but it looks like it's always positive (not just non-zero).

Comment: @VarunVejalla that's not surprising, since $\zeta(\frac32+it)$ is a continuous function of $t$.

Comment: Hint: look at the Euler product for $\zeta(\frac32+it)$, find bounds for the complex argument of each factor, and sum them to show that the argument of $\zeta(\frac32+it)$ is less than $\frac\pi2$ in absolute value.

Comment: @GregMartin Here’s what I’ve got so far. $|\arg \zeta (3/2+it)| \leq |\sum_p \arg(1-p^{-3/2}e^{-it\log(p)})|$. I’m unsure how to progress from here. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: That should be $\arg(1+p^{-3/2}e^{i(\pi - t \cdot \log p)})$. Apologies.

Comment: In my copy, he gives Hutchinson's proof that Re$(\zeta(s))\neq 0$ for Re$(s)=3/2$ on p129.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the proof from Edwards' book, p129:

[image]

Comment: How does this imply the real part is non-zero?

Comment: So, the result rests on the inequality $$-\pi/2<|\text{Im}\log\zeta(s)|<\pi/2.$$ Recall that Im $ \log(z)=\arg(z)\pm 2\pi k$ for any complex $z$. For a complex number to have real part $=0$, its argument must be $\pm \pi/2$. This is shown to be impossible by the calculation.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @MartinR  The person who posted this question has a copy of this very book. I was making a point.